# MySQL foreign key on two columns: integer AND string

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I have tables for `questions` and `answers`, each having a primary key `id`.

And a table `votes` that has the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `answers` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   //whatever
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
CREATE TABLE `questions` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   //whatever
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
CREATE TABLE `votes` (
  `item_model` varchar(25) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `item_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `vote` int(1) NOT NULL,
   KEY `item_id_model` (`item_model`,`item_id`)
)

The index on votes consists of 2 columns:
item_model: string - can have one of 2 values: 'Question' or 'Answer' 
item_id: integer  - references the question or answer's id
```

How do I add a Foreign key constraint on `votes` to reference the id on the tables `questions` and `answers`. Is there any way of doing it by combining the two variables to make up the unique reference (`item_model` and `item_id`) ?

Or is my chosen structure for votes bad practice, meaning I should create two pivot tables `answer_vote` and `question_vote`?

Comment: Post your current `SHOW CREATE TABLE ` output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an answer to the first question...

No, it's not possible to combine the two columns `(item_model,item_id)` into a foreign key constraint that references two possible tables, depending on the value of `item_model`.

You could keep the design. Just with the current implementation, it's just not possible to declare a FOREIGN KEY constraint like that.

---

As far as alternative designs, one possibility to consider would be to define *two* separate columns, one as a FK to `question`, the other as a FK to `answer`

```
  id            int COMMENT 'the vote id'
  item_model    ENUM('Question','Answer')
  question_id   int NULL      COMMENT 'FK ref question.id'
  answer_id     int NULL      COMMENT 'FK ref answer.id' 
  vote          TINYINT
```

Then we could declare two separate foreign key constraints.

If you wanted to enforce a rule that answer_id should be NULL and question_id should be populated (non-NULL) when item_model is 'Question', that could be enforced in BEFORE INSERT and BEFORE UPDATE triggers.

Comment: In your alternative solution, item_model becomes useless right? Do you suggest removing it or does it have a purpose I am not seeing?

Comment: In the first alternative I proposed considering, yes, storing `item_model` would be redundant, since that could be derived from a condition testing whether the  `question_id` or the `answer_id` column is populated. It's definitely redundant. It might still have some use. I'd remove it if there was no benefit to having it. (We would still need to have triggers to enforce a rule that only one of `question_id` or `answer_id` could be populated. If the `item_model` column is kept, the trigger could maintain the column, based on which FK is populated.) Having that column might make queries simpler.